# Inconsistent `with` behavior - no access within functions - is this a chrome bug?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Let's suppress for a minute the "don't use `with`" chorus and suppose that I have a legitimate use case*. [If I have this code](http://jsbin.com/dajuw/1/edit?js,console)

```
with({x: "hi"}) {
  console.log("outside x is", x);
  function aFunc() {
    console.log("inside a func x is", x);
  }
  aFunc();
}
```

In IE11 and Firefox, both statements print "hi". In chrome I get a `ReferenceError` on x within the loop.

Which is the correct behavior? Is this a chrome bug?

---

*. The use case is that I am making an in browser IDE environment that allows users to enter javascript while providing additional functionality, and don't want to attach functions directly to the global scope (think jsbin/jsfiddle but for a specific task).

Comment: It doesn't really matter who is correct if the behavior differs...

Comment: @dandavis sure it does, it matters who I report the issue to

Comment: you can run the user-supplied code in a new Function, and pass pseudo-globals as arguments which will behave just like globals to the user-code, but without using with() or polluting the global namespace. that also allows you to prevent access to certain named variables by not passing an argument to one/more of the formal parameters when calling the generated function.

Comment: Yes, there are workarounds - that one requires that I know ahead of time what's inside the with. I do, but I don't want to remember to add stuff there when I add it to the object. I could always build up the `Function` with `eval` to mimic a `with`. :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which is the correct behavior?

There is none specified. The problem is with your code: You have a function declaration inside a `with` block, which is invalid. Function declarations must be top-level program/function code.

Read more about [function declarations in blocks](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#function-declarations-in-blocks) and [how they are handled](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#function-statements) in different browsers at Kangax' excellent site.

> Is this a chrome bug?

No. Change your code to

```
with({x: "hi"}) {
  console.log("outside x is", x);
  var aFunc = function() {
    console.log("inside a func x is", x);
  }
  aFunc();
}
```

An IEFE should also work:

```
with({x: "hi"}) (function(){
  console.log("outside x is", x);
  function aFunc() {
    console.log("inside a func x is", x);
  }
  aFunc();
}());
```

Comment: Interesting. Surrounding in an IIFE works indeed. Do you think its worth it reporting it to chrome as an inconsistency?

Comment: No, it's not an inconsistency. The `aFunc` declaration simply gets hoisted, where it does not have access to `x`. Other browsers (Opera, newer Safaris) do it like that as well.

Comment: Oh that's a good point about hoisting. So it's firefox and IE behaving badly then, and they should be hoisting it out of the `with` block?

Comment: No. The whole code is syntactically invalid. Firefox (and apparently new IE) do accept it as a "function statement" though, and other browsers accept it as a "function declaration". You might want to report a feature-request that you would like to receive a *warning* in the console when such syntax is detected.